# DocuSign API - Send On Behalf - .NET

Tags: docusignapi

We are looking at the DocuSign API integration using .NET. 
I've managed to send an email from this correctly and added fields to the form programmatically however I could do with knowing how to use the Send On Behalf feature.

It looks like in the `APILogin()` function I need to add a default header called `X-DocuSign-Act-As-User` and then the email address (SOB is enabled on the API account). But then it says I need something to do with a token for this user? But not sure where I get this from?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

`X-DocuSign-Act-As-User` header is only applicable when using OAuth tokens.  For non-token usage, add the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header.

Example from the GUIDE:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication:<DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>bob.smith@gmail.com</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Where `{name}` is the email address of your API Initiator and `{password}` is the password of your API Initiator.  Those credentials are used to authenticate the API call, but the envelope will be created and owned by "bob.smith@gmail.com" as the Sender.

Note 1:  "bob.smith@gmail.com", i.e. the on-behalf user, must be an account member with "send envelopes" permissions.
Note 2:  API Initiator credentials - recommendation is to use API Name (the User's GUID) rather than email address, and use the "encrypted password" instead of the plain-text password. This is retrievable via the login_information API call.  These forms of the credentials are not useful for logging into DocuSign via the Web interface.